# Do we have onTapDown and Drag functionality in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listener, gesturedetector

I have a simple usecase which is some how super tricky for a beginner in flutter.

I need these values returned for the scenario explained below

There are 2 containers in a row (green and orange)
[image]

1. OnTapDown on green container it should return ‘Green’ (this is straight forward and done)
2. Without lifting the finger off the screen, I drag my finger over the Orange container and I need that to return ‘Orange’

How do I solve this?

Comment: I have tried using GestureDetector 'onTapDown' and also tried using Listener with these functions 'onPointerDown', 'onPointerMove'

still not able to figure how to execute this

Comment: check this https://github.com/yeasin50/Rotary_phone_lock/blob/51fb0eebeac66720e2df7ae5b0d6279093606096/lib/components/wheel_handler.dart#L306-L329

Comment: Dont forget to upvote and set mark it as resolved ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to wrap your layout with `GestureDetector` and "guess" the position of your elements to then know where the drag ends.

EDIT: Adding a real check on the target position to make it more robust thanks to @GoodSp33d comment:

```
class DragView extends StatefulWidget {
  const DragView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DragViewState createState() => _DragViewState();
}

GlobalKey orangeContainerKey = GlobalKey();
GlobalKey greenContainerKey = GlobalKey();

class _DragViewState extends State<DragView> {
  Rect? getGlobalPaintBounds(GlobalKey element) {
    final renderObject = element.currentContext!.findRenderObject();
    var translation = renderObject?.getTransformTo(null).getTranslation();
    if (translation != null && renderObject?.paintBounds != null) {
      return renderObject?.paintBounds
          .shift(Offset(translation.x, translation.y));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  bool isInRect(double x, double y, Rect? rect) {
    if (rect != null)
      return x >= rect.left &&
          x <= rect.right &&
          y <= rect.bottom &&
          y >= rect.top;
    return false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _cursorX = 0;
    double _cursorY = 0;

    return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
        _cursorX = details.globalPosition.dx;
        _cursorY = details.globalPosition.dy;
      },
      onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
        if (isInRect(
            _cursorX, _cursorY, getGlobalPaintBounds(orangeContainerKey)))
          print("Orange");
        if (isInRect(
            _cursorX, _cursorY, getGlobalPaintBounds(greenContainerKey)))
          print("Green");
      },
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(key: greenContainerKey, color: Colors.green),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(key: orangeContainerKey, color: Colors.orange),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Second edit moving the detection to the onDragUpdate and checks to make it happens only on rect changes:

```
    GlobalKey? currentObject;

      onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
        _cursorX = details.globalPosition.dx;
        _cursorY = details.globalPosition.dy;
        if (isInRect(
            _cursorX, _cursorY, getGlobalPaintBounds(orangeContainerKey))) {
          if (currentObject == null || currentObject != orangeContainerKey) {
            print("Orange");
            currentObject = orangeContainerKey;
          }
        }
        if (isInRect(_cursorX, _cursorY,
            getGlobalPaintBounds(greenContainerKey))) if (currentObject ==
                null ||
            currentObject != greenContainerKey) {
          print("Green");
          currentObject = greenContainerKey;
        }
      },
```

Comment: You can assign keys to both green and orange containers and detect if touch point is in the container or not instead to make it more robust.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply
I tried this, and it returns 'Orange' after Drag Ends right, but i need the value to be returned as soon as it reaches orange

Comment: Then you need to calculate the position in the dragUpdate method and not end, but also add a check that if it is still the same container to not print or do anything.

Comment: @Wapazz it works when i updated in drag update :) 
thanks

Comment: I added to the answer to make it not refresh everytime